# R/exams use styles in reference.docx

Tags: r, pandoc, r-exams

With vanilla pandoc, when converting to docx, it is possible to adapt the paragraph styles in a reference.docx that is passed to pandoc via `--reference-doc=reference.docx`. However, in r-exams this is somewhat limited, as all elements in a converted docx file seem to have the style "Normal". Also custom styles (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles) do not seem to work because of this. Is there any fix/hack to use this pandoc feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Options in exams2pandoc**

When using `exams2pandoc()` you can supply any `options` to be used when calling `pandoc`. So you can set a `reference-doc` but you need to supply the full path to it because the exercises will be processed in a temporary directory and not the current working directory. Thus, you can do:

```
exams2pandoc("capitals.Rmd", options = "--reference-doc=/path/to/reference.docx")
```

The option is passed on in this case but I'm not sure what we would need to do to leverage the styles defined in this reference document. I tried setting the default paragraph style (e.g., using a different font) but this doesn't seem to have an effect. But this may well be due to my lacking skills in Word formatting!

**Details**

If you want to have a closer look at how this could be tweaked, the following may be helpful. The `exams2pandoc()` function internally first creates a .tex file (by default). When using the [capitals](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/capitals/) template as above you will get a file like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide,color,Sweave,url,amsmath,booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}

%% Exam 1
%% 2022-12-01

\begin{enumerate}

  \item
  \textbf{Question}\\
  Which of the following cities are the capital of the corresponding country?
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item São Paulo (Brazil)
    \item Riyadh (Saudi Arabia)
    \item Warsaw (Poland)
    \item Tokyo (Japan)
    \item Istanbul (Turkey)
  \end{enumerate}

  \textbf{Solution}\\
  
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item False. The capital of Brazil is Brasilia.
    \item True. Riyadh is the capital of Saudi Arabia.
    \item True. Warsaw is the capital of Poland.
    \item True. Tokyo is the capital of Japan.
    \item False. The capital of Turkey is Ankara.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Then subsequently this is converted to .docx via

```
pandoc -o capitals.docx capitals.tex
```

where you can additionally insert further options as described above.

Maybe you can provide some guidance on what would be necessary to leverage other styles from a reference docx?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailled answer! I since moved on to Python Pandoc, also because I am more familiar with Python. The logic of the reference.doc is similar though. Easiest is to generate the doc first without the reference and see which Word styles are used by your doc. Then adapt _these specific_ styles in the reference.doc to your preferences. In Python Pandoc it is also possible to assign _custom_ styles to certain elements of one's input file and to define these custom styles in the reference.doc. This increases the flexibility quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes sense. I would expect that it is possible to define templates that also produce custom styles with R/Markdown but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the details here. If anyone can provide further hints how to accomplish this in `knitr` or `rmarkdown` etc., feel free to let me know.